# Issue deploying Rails 5 app using Devise to Heroku and to Github

Tags: heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this app working perfectly on my local Windows system. It's a basic CRUD exercise on Rails 5 using Devise that I was assigned. I tried to push to Heroku and got an error stating it didn't support sqlite, so I moved it to development, test only as in Michael Hartl's tutorial. It finally worked and it's living at: https://sheltered-brook-53935.herokuapp.com/

But when I try to access the Sign Up or Log In routes I get a Heroku error saying that something went wrong.

Terminal output after I run git push heroku master
https://gist.github.com/garosan/c3246b5bb9ff347ca0e9ea0e96ad413b

Heroku Logs
https://gist.github.com/garosan/3c3ccca6c4f6a8a0c64f829f85341470

Additionally, I need to share the repo for someone to check my work, I pushed it to https://github.com/garosan/rails-habits-tracker but when I download the zip and try to run it I get the dreaded ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError. This can be solved by doing rails db:migrate but the person checking my repo shouldn't need to do this. Any idea as to how can I fix it?

Comment: The Heroku deployment worked after running: heroku run rails db:migrate but I still can get my repo to work smoothly after cloning it so clearly there's a problem with my migrations! Oddly enough, if I run git status I don't have anything pending to add or commit so I'm guessing it's something related to a file that gets gitignored when pushing to Github.

Comment: Can you add code from `HabitsController#index` ?

Comment: https://github.com/garosan/rails-habits-tracker/blob/master/app/controllers/habits_controller.rb here is the whole controller

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your code , I think `current_user` is missing , If you are using devise make sure you are checking `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your controller so It will redirect to login page if user is not present. For debugging comment your code in index action and check `puts current_user.inspect` if it is coming or not.

```
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def index
     @habits = Habit.where(user_id:current_user.id)
     #current_user is not present in your case so it is throwing nil class error 
   end
end
```

You can check more options here [Devise controller helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

Comment: Thank you, that wasn't actually the problem but I already submitted the code. This was my first contact with Rails so, just a matter of keeping on learning.